# Magento 2 - amounts are not rounded in sales_order_payment table

Tags: magento2

I have a payment method, which at the time of doing the place order, is saved in the table sales_order_payment the amounts wrong. I attach an image.

[image]

The last 4 decimals of the amount_paid field, is not the same as base_amount_ordered

In order to save the order, I get this: $ order-> getGrandTotal () = 31.0755 when it should be 31.0800

I have tried to modify it in this way:

1)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
$quote = $quoteFactory->create()->load($order->getQuoteId());

$order->setBaseGrandTotal(31.0800);
$order->setGrandTotal(31.0800);
```

2)

```
$order->setSubtotal(31.0800)
       ->setBaseSubtotal(31.0800)
       ->setGrandTotal(31.0800)
       ->setBaseGrandTotal(31.0800);
$quote->setSubtotal(31.0800)
        ->setBaseSubtotal(31.0800)
        ->setGrandTotal(31.0800)
        ->setBaseGrandTotal(31.0800);
$quote->save();
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

3)

```
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->setSubtotal(31.0800);
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->setBaseSubtotal(31.0800);
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->setGrandTotal(31.0800);
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->setBaseGrandTotal(31.0800);
$quote->save($quote->collectTotals());
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
```

but in no way I have managed to set the correct value, can you give me an idea or help me in how can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 You can get this by following way inside **phtml** file

```
$this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format(50,2),true,false);
```

If you want to get price with currency then check this [Link](https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-get-formatted-price-with-currency/)

Comment: doesnt work, my problem es in the database in the table sales_order_payment. When I save a order with pay, the fields values (amount_paid and base_amount_ordered) dont match. 

What you send me is to change format to visual mode, or at least I can not make it change with that code in my database